# Docker image Tor OBFS4 Bridge "/var/lib/tor is not owned by this user (debian-tor, 100) but by <unknown> (999)" after update from 4.7.10 to 4.8.10

Tags: docker, compose

I am deploying a docker image of Tor Bridge OBFS4. I use the standard docker-compose.yml and .env file with my edits. Nothing fancy, really. After seeing that my Tor Bridge Version 4.7.10 was flagged as not recommeded I downed the container, pulled the new version and then trouble started.
After `docker compose pull && docker compose up -d` I see the following errors when I inspect the logs:

```
Jan 30 21:29:42.972 [notice] Tor 0.4.8.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.0.11, Zlib 1.2.13, Liblzma 5.4.1, Libzstd 1.5.4 and Glibc 2.36 as libc.
Jan 30 21:29:42.972 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/
Jan 30 21:29:42.972 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jan 30 21:29:42.974 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 6372 MB. You can override this by setting MaxMemInQueues by hand.
Jan 30 21:29:42.976 [notice] Opening OR listener on 0.0.0.0:12345
Jan 30 21:29:42.976 [notice] Opened OR listener connection (ready) on 0.0.0.0:12345
Jan 30 21:29:42.976 [notice] Opening OR listener on [::]:12345
Jan 30 21:29:42.976 [notice] Opened OR listener connection (ready) on [::]:12345
Jan 30 21:29:42.976 [notice] Opening Extended OR listener on 127.0.0.1:0
Jan 30 21:29:42.976 [notice] Extended OR listener listening on port 46291.
Jan 30 21:29:42.976 [notice] Opened Extended OR listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:46291
Jan 30 21:29:42.977 [warn] /var/lib/tor is not owned by this user (debian-tor, 100) but by <unknown> (999). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Jan 30 21:29:42.977 [notice] Closing partially-constructed OR listener connection (ready) on 0.0.0.0:12345
Jan 30 21:29:42.977 [notice] Closing partially-constructed OR listener connection (ready) on [::]:12345
Jan 30 21:29:42.977 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Extended OR listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:46291
Jan 30 21:29:42.977 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't create private data directory "/var/lib/tor"
Jan 30 21:29:42.977 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

I am quite sure that I did not change any volumes that are handed to docker via .yml file. Yet, somehow the error persists. The docker user did not change; other docker container run fine.
Any ideas or suggestions? Tank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild the container using:

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build <your-service-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

There haven't been any changes to [the Docker file repository](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/anti-censorship/docker-obfs4-bridge), so it seems like there's an issue with [the latest docker image 0.15](https://hub.docker.com/layers/thetorproject/obfs4-bridge/0.15/images/sha256-404962dd86fc77e02b32b04a14ac70efb8e7c0b9f1ef1549ad6b682662aeb0f9?context=explore).
I built the docker image locally, and it is running Tor 0.4.8.10 without needing any changes.